# Embede IPythonNotebook into iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, jupyter-notebook

All.
I'm trying to embed IpythonNotebook into my page. I want to do that like wakari guys (https://wakari.io/) via iFrame. 
But by default it's forbidden to frame Ipython NB.
When

```
<iframe id="NBframe" src="http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled0.ipynb"></iframe>
```

I receive

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled0.ipynb' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

How can I frame this page? May be some configuration somewhere in Ipython?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

Need to add this to ipython_notebook_config

```
c.NotebookApp.webapp_settings = {'headers': {'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOW-FROM http://example.com/'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 2.x you need to set the X-Frame-Option, on current master and upcoming 3.0 use CSP.

In both case see here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/7016

Comment: Thanks Matt for the guideline. Finally I found out a config which I have to add to my profile.